# get next upcoming game, display on mondays

Tags: php, mysql

There will be games at saturdays but not every weekend. I Want to show on a new week if there is an upcoming game that following saturday.

I was thinking of something like this to check 6 days ahead if we are on ex monday, if there is a game that saturday it should find it. But of course it lacks parts, just a start but Im stuck. As for now it finds the next game which is 1 month away, it should only show if there is one that week.

```
"Select * From games Where date > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class to find the date for next Saturday:

```
$nextSaturday = new DateTime('next Saturday');
```

From there, just select where the date equals `$nextSaturday->format('Y-m-d')` to find the games (if any) for next Saturday.

Comment: If its possible I want to use something like unix time maybe, is that possible? Maybe with strtotime() or mktime() and search in some interval.

Comment: @user1225840:  That's not a problem at all.  You would just use [the `getTimestamp()` method](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php), e.g. `$nextSaturday->getTimestamp()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to ask the database to fetch is "all games WITHIN the next 6 days" really

```
SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE()
AND `date` <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

... or you could use `BETWEEN` ...

```
SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `date` 
BETWEEN CURDATE()
AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

---

[edit]

Having just worked out what you meant by "display on mondays" in the question title ... you only actually want to execute the query on Mondays :)

So you'll either only want to **run** the query on Mondays (done at the application level) or run the query with an `AND DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2` in it so it'd be something like

```
SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE()
AND `date` <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
AND DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2
```

Although that's rather inefficient as you'll **always** run the query even if there's no need to - it would be better to have the application **only execute it on Mondays**.

In which case you're better off with drrcknlsn's solution using PHP's `DateTime` object and doing something like (or munging the whole thing into a Cron job):

```
if(date("N") == 1) {
  $oNextSaturday = new DateTime('next Saturday');
  $sFetchUpcomingGames = "SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `date` = '{$oNextSaturday->format('Y-m-d')}'";

  //execute the database query and perform relevant outputs, and so on
}
```

Comment: Lets say I want to display that game on mondays so ppl can buy tickets beforehand? Then the current date should be Mondays but how do I set that in the query, can we use DAYOFWEEK(date)?

Comment: Why would the current date matter? What this query will fetch is _any game_ happening in the next 6 days whether the date on which the query takes place is Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday ... whatever. Or do you **only** want to run the query on Mondays? In which case you'll need to either filter it at the application layer (so that the SQL isn't executed unless it's Monday) or add something like `AND DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2` to the query.